# how to unset session_cache_limiter in php

Tags: php

I have set `session_cache_limiter('private_no_expire');` before `session_start();` so that the user can use the Back button without 'Document Expired' page being shown. But now, I am unable to destroy the session and log the user out. What should I do to unset the `session_cache_limiter`?

Comment: What are you using to log the user out?

Comment: unset($_SESSION);header('Location:index.php');

Comment: You could try `$_SESSION = array();` instead.

Comment: I tried that too but it didn.t work.

Comment: Well, how do you determine whether a user is logged in?

Comment: `if(isset($_SESSION['sessionLogin']) && !empty($_SESSION['sessionLogin']))`

Comment: To log them out you have to `session_start()` first.

Comment: yes I have done that as well. It does not clear cuz I've set the session_cache_limiter to `private_no_expire`.

Comment: Are you sure that your server is being hit when the user clicks the logout link?

Comment: Yes! Logout works fine if I comment out the session_cache_limiter

Answer (score 0):

[session_unset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php) should work fine from my tests for clearing all the session variables.

Here is my login file (ie index.php) :

```
<?php
session_cache_limiter('private_no_expire');

session_start();

$_SESSION['test'] = true;

echo '<pre>';
print_r($_SESSION);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Here's the code I've tested it with (the logout file) :

```
<?php
session_cache_limiter('private_no_expire');
session_start();

session_unset();

echo '<pre>';
print_r($_SESSION);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

The above code works for me.

Comment: add `session_cache_limiter('private_no_expire');` before `session_start();` and then try